# Error al compartir PDF guardado en la almacanamiento interno del app

Tags: java, android

mi app genera un PDF y lo guarda en la memoria interna del teléfono, todo bien hasta ahí. Lo que necesito hacer ahora es que se pueda compartir ese PDF. Me sale un error ("este achivo no es compatible") abre la ventana de compartir pero al darle click a gmail o whatsapp, sale ese error.
Este es mi código para generar el PDF (revisé en el explorador de archivos de android studio y si está ahí y abre ok)

```
public static void generateAndOpenPDF(Context context, byte[] data, String filename) {
        File outputDir = context.getFilesDir();
        File outputFile = new File(outputDir, filename);

        Document document = new Document();

        try {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            outputStream.write(data);
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            Log.e("PDFGenerator", "DocumentException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("PDFGenerator", "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        //openPDF(context, outputFile);
        sharePDF(context, outputFile);
    }
```

Este es el código que uso para compartir:

```
private static  void sharePDF(Context context,File file){
        if (file.exists()) {
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(file.toString()));
            shareIntent.setType("application/pdf");
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Compartir PDF"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

parece que el error esta aquí "File outputDir = context.getFilesDir();"
Para obtener la dirección correcta de tu archivo deberías usar FileProvider

```
 Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(PdfView.this, PdfView.this.getPackageName() + ".provider",file,nombreArchivo);
```

Donde file seria: file = new File(dir, nombreArchivo);
dir contendría la dirección real

```
File dir = new File((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/PDF"));
```